# Where oracle saves lobs?

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle, so I don't know how lobs are saved, like in postgresql all lobs are saved in a table ( pg_largeobject) and all tables with lobs column have an id for this "main table".
So does oracle save lobs in a table and all tables just have an id to this "main table" or each table has his own copy of the lob.

Comment: There are a lot of useful  [whitepapers about lobs](https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=oracle+lobs+whitepaper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a doc in oracle that explains how he manage his storage with LOBs, 
[how storage works in oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm#i1006378)

Answer (score 0):

Internal LOBs are stored within the database, as table columns. External LOBs are stored outside the database as operating system files.  Only a reference to the actual OS file is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see LOB object storage details, you can use the following views:

```
DBA_LOBS
DBA_SEGMENTS
DBA_EXTENTS
```

DBA_LOBS: owner, table, column, segment info for the LOB table column

DBA_SEGMENTS: logical storage unit details

DBA_EXTENTS: block storage unit details